# Form POST or sessions?

Tags: php, forms

If you have an item where you allow users to add comments, how can you pass which item the user is replying too?

I've though of using a hidden field in a form, however this can be easily changed using plugins such as firebug:

```
<form method="post" action="blah">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
<!-- other form data here -->
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Or just simply using a session:

```
$_SESSION['item_id'] = $item_id
```

Is there a safe way to send the item data in a form?

**Edit:**
This is *after* validation,... I do implement some XSS protection (form tokens etc). The reason I was asking was just to know what the best practise is.

I though of doing something like

```
$_SESSION['item_id'] = $id //this is set when they visit the current item
```

then in the form have a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $id?>">
```

Finally check the session matches the id clicked:

```
if ($_SESSION('item_id') !== $item_id) //the value posted in the form
{
   die('There\'s got to be a morning after
       If we can hold on through the night
       We have a chance to find the sunshine
       Let\'s keep on looking for the light');
}
```

However after reading some of your comments I guess this is a bad idea?

To be fair (@Surreal Dreams): it isn't that big a deal if they do change the id, I as I've said,I was just looking for the best practice.

Cheers.

Comment: For your particular application, what's the risk of the user spoofing the post id?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a session the way you suggested would screw up cases where (1) a visitor opens several different articles in multiple tabs, and (2) tries to write a reply on any tab other than the one that was opened last. The user might even write two replies simultaneously in different tabs; I sometimes do that on StackOverflow. Web developers so easily forget that today's visitors may have several browser tabs open at the same time. Really, we don't use IE6 anymore.

A solution would be to make `$_SESSION['item_id']` an array of recently viewed article IDs, but then you won't be able to stop some Firebug user (or any other tech savvy person) from replying to a previously viewed article. Adding time limits won't change anything, either.

But why would somebody intentionally change the ID of the post to which they're replying, except to troll or spam the site? And if somebody really wanted to screw your site, they can easily get around any protection by making their bot request the appropriate page just before posting a spam comment. You'd be much better off investing in a better CSRF token generator, spam filter, rate limiter, etc.

Comment: +1 for bringing up multiple tabs. Far too many sites fail when multiple tabs are used

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you're probably okay using the hidden form element. If you're really concerned about someone changing it, you could always `base64()` encode it to make it harder to change.

However, you could always set a session variable on the page and then when the form is submitted call that value back.

**Form**

```
<?
session_start();

//Make a random ID for this form instance
$form_id = rand(1, 500);

//Set session variable for this form
$_SESSION[$form_id]['item_id'] = $item_id;
?>

<form method="post" action="process.php?n=<?=$form_id?>">
<!-- form data here -->
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Process**

```
<?
session_start();

//Process only if the number submitted matches the SESSION variable
if(array_key_exists($_GET['n'], $_SESSION) {
  //Process tasks
  echo $_SESSION[$_GET['n']['item_id'];

  //Unset session variable when done processing
  unset($_SESSION[$_GET['n']);
}
?>
```

Comment: The only problem with $_SESSION is: what if the user has 2 tabs open at the same time?

Comment: Sessions are held at the server level. Once a session cookie is set in the browser, it affects the entire browser until the session is destroyed or the browser is closed completely. Regardless, having more than one browser window open will not affect what you're trying to accomplish in this form.

Comment: Exactly what? I'm not sure I understand what your concern is. If you create that SESSION variable every time the form is loaded, it will always be the correct "item_id". When the form is done processing, you unset the SESSION variable. If it doesn't get used, it doesn't get used. It's impossible for the user visiting your form to change that SESSION variable; Only you can set and unset it.

Comment: @mririgo: What if I this form open twice, in 2 tabs?  What if each tab has a different item_id?  How will you know which item_id is which?

Comment: If the user goes to the comment page for item X, then in another tab, goes to the comment page for item Y, the session is pointing to item Y...if they switch to the first tab and save their comment it will appear under the wrong item. I believe that's what @Rocket was getting at. I would agree that sessions are bad for this, and to use a hidden form variable, while on the server side checking to make sure they have permission to post a comment to said item.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, that's exactly what I was getting at.

Comment: @Dan: He doesn't want to use hidden form fields, so let's find a way to make it work with sessions.  @Rocket: Check updated code, it avoids using hidden fields, but still passes a GET variable to the process script. Since it's a random number, the worst that can happen is that the ID on the process value and the ID on the SESSION variable we added don't line up, and then you don't process. That way, false data can't be sent by changing that hidden variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hidden field.

If the user modifies the DOM to say it is a reply to a different comment, so what? It only affects them.

If you want to limit what the user can reply to, then you need to implement a proper access control layer and not try to enforce it in the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed from the angry, pitchfork-wielding mob, neither solution is very satisfying due to issues like multiple tabs.

If there is a genuine concern about people being able to post comments on another object then the one they were initially visiting, consider storing them in $_SESSION using an array, and having them post the ID back using a hidden form. If the value posted back is not in the array, then it is obviously a post that he was not looking at.

To increase tamper-proofness, considering about hashing the ID (of course with a generous salting), and storing those in the array.

Do note that I feel you may be trying to solve the wrong problem here; why not validate if the person has access to make a comment on the post he is commenting on? If you have access, then you should be allowed to comment - if you want to tamper with the ID and make your comment end up under the wrong post.. well, that's basically your problem. I mean, the user could also go to the other post, and make the wrong comment there manually... so what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a form like this

```
<?
$saltedhash = md5("MYSEED"+$item_id;)
?>

<form method="post" action="blah">
<!-- form data here -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<? echo $item_id ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_hash" value="<? echo $saltedhash ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This was, you can always check that the passed item_id matches its corresponding hash and see if the user changed it.

However, as pointed by others, this won't prevent the user from posting on different items as if they can get the hash from somewhere... An access control mechanism would be preferable

Answer (score -1):

Using $_SESSION to store the post ID is the ideal solution since it does avoid the ability to modify that value.

That being said, what are the benefits to someone doing that?  As well, many comment systems have an approval process that requires an admin to approve the comment before posting anyway.

But yes, I would recommend sticking with the session value.

Comment: The only problem with $_SESSION is: what if the user has 2 tabs open at the same time?